# Electron js, Sudo-prompt, on macos returns "command failed" for copy and mv

Tags: node.js, installation, electron, filesystems, sudo

I need to allow my electron app to copy or move directories in system directories. I use sudo-prompt to elevate the right and run mv or cp -R command but the package returns Command failed error on each.

Thanks for your help to make works sudo-prompt with cp or mv command or for all other solutions to achieve the same aim.

Here's my code :

```
const command: string[] = [
      'mv',
      '/path/to/my/source/mydirectory',
      '/Library/path/to/destination/',
    ];
    sudo.exec(
      command.join(' '),
      options,
      (error, stdout, stderr) => {
        if (stdout) {
          console.log(`[sudo-prompt] received stdout: ${stdout}`);
        }

        if (stderr) {
          console.log(`[sudo-prompt] received stderr: ${stderr}`);
        }

        if (error) {
          console.log(error);
        } else {
          console.log(undefined);
        }
      },
    );
```

And here's the error :

```
Error: Command failed: mv /path/to/my/source/mydirectory /Library/path/to/destination/
mv: rename /path/to/my/source/mydirectory to /Library/path/to/destination/mydirectory: Operation not permitted

    at myApp/node_modules/sudo-prompt/index.js:390:27
    at FSReqCallback.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (node:internal/fs/read_file_context:68:3) {
  code: 1
}
```

With cp :

```
const command: string[] = [
      'cp',
      '-R',
      '/path/to/my/source/mydirectory',
      '/Library/path/to/destination/',
    ];
```

The error is :

```
Error: Command failed: cp -R /path/to/my/source/mydirectory /Library/path/to/destination/
cp: /path/to/my/source/mydirectory: unable to copy extended attributes to /Library/path/to/destination/mydirectory: Operation not permitted
cp: /path/to/my/source/mydirectory: Operation not permitted

    at myApp/node_modules/sudo-prompt/index.js:390:27
    at FSReqCallback.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (node:internal/fs/read_file_context:68:3) {
  code: 1
}
```

The directory is created at the right place but is empty.

Notice :

- when I run the command "sudo mv /path/to/my/source/mydirectory /Library/path/to/destination/" or "sudo cp -R /path/to/my/source/mydirectory /Library/path/to/destination/" in terminal every thing work perfectly
- running sudo_prompt code with "mkdir /Library/path/to/destination/mydirectory" or "touch /Library/path/to/destination/testfile.txt" work also perfectly

The problem seems to be in the way sudo-prompt runs cp and mv.